# Why do I get an out_of_range exception here?

Tags: c++, outofrangeexception

Currently doing a project at uni where at first I need to de-hyphenate a string, seemed pretty simple however when i run the program it has an error `WeirdPuncProgram.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x004EF898`

It also is not returning the string value properly, inside the function `answer()` is changed and hyphens are removed but once it comes out its just the original input again.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string answer;

string hyphonRemover(string answer)
{
   string spacer = " ";
   int h;
   for (int i = 0; i < answer.length(); i++)
   {
      h = answer.find_first_of("-");
      answer.replace(h, 1, spacer);
   }
   return answer;
}


int main()
{

   cout << "Type a sentence which contains punctuation and ill remove it for you! " << endl << endl;
   getline(cin, answer);
   hyphonRemover(answer);
   cout << answer << endl;
   system("pause");
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: You are not checking if `answer.find_first_of("-");` returns a negative number, which happens if no match is found. Using a negative index will cause trouble on the next line.

Comment: Also, you call `hyphonRemover` and then throw away the result without storing it.

Answer (score 1):

every use of `answer` in `hyphonRemover()` will be local variable, not global `answer` you defined above.

thus the function will modify only its local variable.

Comment: that is true, however it is not an answer to the question :)